# Moodle: moodle_role_assign using web services api

Tags: php, mysql, mamp, moodle

I have created a user using the api successfully. I am trying to assign a role to the created user and I am using the moodle_role_assign webservices function to perform that function. But when I am trying to do so, I am getting an exception with the message "**Invalid parameter value detected, execution can not continue.**"

This is the request URL

> http://localhost:8888/moodle21/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=24053894192315aa6c23764c700b59c6&wsfunction=moodle_role_assign&assignments[0][roleid]=5&assignments[0][userid]=33&assignments[0][contextid]=10

I would really appreciate if you could help me with this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Moodle 2.2 (at this time, it's master branch: https://github.com/moodle/moodle) and turn Moodle debug mode >= NORMAL. From Moodle 2.2, the error message will indicate which parameter is wrong and what was expected.

Comment: Note, as your parameters seem correct to me I suspect that the user you are using hasn't 'moodle/role:assign' capability on the context.